# When is the programmer truly thinking in an object oriented manner?

Tags: javascript

**What I am doing here:** What you will see below is the manifestation of uselessness in code but helps me as a general exercise to understand OOP in Javascript.

**Problem and Question:** I have been hearing of OOP the entire time. I know it means writing modular code, but **when** exactly are you writing object oriented? I mean functions are objects or is the programmer writing in OOP when he uses a conjunction of classes, methods, prototype inheritance and object arrays?

So here is what I have been writing (dont laugh!) and Im wondering if this is considered valid OOP coding style or plain stupidity:

Of course I would thank you guys alot (yes I said alot) with some yummy points if you could enlighten me a bit : )

**My idea of basic OOP:**

```
obj = {
    words: {
        now: 'Now',
        finally: 'Finally!'
    }
}

function Parentclass(n){
    this.nameString = 'Works'
}

function Childclass (n){
    this.name = this.nameString;
    this.fn = function fn(n) {
        alert(n + ' ' + this.name + ' ' + obj.words.now)
    }
}

Childclass.prototype = new Parentclass();

var x = new Childclass();

x.fn('Everything')
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cLbgwdmx/7/

To make things clear: Yes I did read the mozilla documentation...and yes I did google searches...but hey, would be cool if you can give me the last anti-doubt-injection.

Comment: Did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming ?

Comment: @FelixKling yes I have

Comment: You think OOP when you treat things as objects (in contrast to series of bytes). There's nothing more behind it (except some decades of buzzwording).

Comment: @Bergi I assume this doesnt have to be used everywhere though, right? I mean OOP makes sense depending on the complexity of a program I think. If a program is complex, then making usage of OOP makes more sense. If the program is simple then a procedural workflow

Comment: I'd recommend http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-objects

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [programmers.se].

Comment: @MadaraUchiha this is a bit broad and unclear and would not be a good question for Programmers. Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: *"I assume this doesnt have to be used everywhere though, right?"* There are also people vehemently opposed to OOP and advocate functional programming instead. So no, OOP certainly doesn't have to be used everywhere. Use it if it makes sense to model your app this way and don't "overuse" it.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for giving me the "push" I needed